# Mandrill API with Handlebars "each-loop" not working

Tags: go, mandrill

Met problem when using Mandrill API to send transactional newsletters. I chose Handlebars for the template parameters. The user name was shown correctly, but data in the list (post titles) were empty. Please help indicate if anything I did wrong. Thank you!

The template is as below, sent to the endpoint `/messages/send.json` :

```
func genHTMLTemplate() string {
    return "code generated template<br>" +
        "Hi {{name}}, <br>" + 
        "{{#each posts}}<div>" +
        "TITLE {{title}}, THIS {{this}}<br>" +
        "</div>{{/each}}"
}
```

The API log in my Settings panel in mandrillapp.com shows the parameters:

```
{
"key": "xxxxxxxxxx",
"message": {
        :
    "merge_language": "handlebars",
    "global_merge_vars": null,
    "merge_vars": [
        {
            "rcpt": "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
            "vars": [
                {
                    "name": "posts",
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "title": "title A"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "title B"
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "name",
                    "content": "John Doe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
      :
    },
    :
}
```

And below is the email received. "title A" and "title B" are expected after "TITLE".

```
code generated template
Hi John Doe,
TITLE, THIS Array
TITLE, THIS Array
```

Comment: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-dynamic-content
Use this link to use handle bars in your code its so easy with global variables.

Answer (score 3):

Mandrill decided to create custom handlebars helpers with some horrible, HORRIBLE names:

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-Dynamic-Content#inline-helpers-available-in-mandrill

`title` and `url` will definitely give you grief if your objects happen to have keys named `title` and `url`as well. Why they didn't name their helpers something like `toTitleCase` and `encodeUrl` is beyond me.

As far as arrays and `#each` is concerned, you can work around it by using `{{this.title}}` instead of `{{title}}`.

Answer (score 1):

After testing with Mandrill's sample code [here](http://blog.mandrill.com/handlebars-for-templates-and-dynamic-content.html) I found the key "title" just doesn't work. Dunno the reason (a reserved keyword of Mandrill?) but replace it with "title1", "titleX" or something else it can be rendered correctly.

```
{
    "name": "posts",
    "content": [
        {
           "title": "blah blah"  // "title1" or something else works
        },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

while using handlebars as the merge language 'title' is the reserved helpername which is used in handlebars which makes your text in title case. If you do only {{title}} by default it considers as title the empty text. try giving it {{title title}} which should work or changing the key name to something else ( if you dont want your title in title case )

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but it could be of use to someone trying to debug this issue currently. Take note of this point in the Mandrill [documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/docs/templates-dynamic-content/)

> There are two main ways to add dynamic content via merge tags: Handlebars or the Mailchimp merge language. You may already be familiar with the Mailchimp merge language from creating and editing Mailchimp templates. We also offer a custom implementation of Handlebars, which is open source and offers greater flexibility.

> To set your merge language, navigate to Sending Defaults and select Mailchimp or Handlebars from the Merge Language drop-down menu.

I've run into a similar issue on Sending Blue, where their default configuration does not enable handle bars so it won't evaluate them.